# Outlook Word Editor not saving changes Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, addin-express

I wonder if anyone can please help. I am trying to modify emails in Outlook and print them taking out some of the text of previous emails in the thread.  Something like this, although generating the ranges is more complicated in actuality.

MailItem newItem = ((Outlook.MailItem)item);
  WORD.Document objDoc = (Outlook.MailItem)newItem).GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
  WORD.Range R = objDoc.Range(0, 200);
  r.Delete ();

newItem.Print();

objDoc.Undo(); // undo the chnages now printed

now although I see the word range delete the text, when I print the email it still has all the text in, how can I get the altered text back into the email to print?  Then I would like to undo the chnages after printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866979(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class to save your changes.